# wicket how to update the header of modal<T>

Tags: ajax, header, wicket

I'm making a page using wicket.
The main page consists of a table displaying invoice information.
In the last column of the table has a link for each one of the invoices displaying the full information for that invoice, by opening a modal.
I'm using de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.dialog.Modal

My goal is when I open the modal, the header of the modal shows the invoice number of that invoice that was opened.

I'm able to get it only after refreshing the page, and if I open the modal of another invoice the header is not updated, it shows the number of the previous invoice. I have to refresh again the page.

I don't know how to open a modal that shows in the header the number of the respective invoice without refreshing the page.

**below the markup of the main page.**

```
<wicket:extend>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>
                <wicket:message key="invoices-welcome">[Welcome message]</wicket:message>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span wicket:id="navigator">[dataview navigator]</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" class="table table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Invoice number</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                <tr wicket:id="rows">
                    <td><span wicket:id="status">[status]</span></td>
                    <td><span wicket:id="invoiceN">[invoiceN]</span></td>
                    <td><span wicket:id="supplier">[supplier]</span></td>
                    <td><span wicket:id="customer">[customer]</span></td>
                    <td><span wicket:id="amount">[amount]</span></td>
                    <td><a wicket:id="showModal">View</a></td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div wicket:id="modal"></div>
    </wicket:extend>
```

**Java code of the main page**

```
package nl.riskco.liberobc.web.pages.invoices;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.navigation.paging.PagingNavigator;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.Item;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.DataView;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.ListDataProvider;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;

import nl.riskco.liberobc.client.business.model.InvoiceDomain;
import nl.riskco.liberobc.client.business.services.IInvoiceService;
import nl.riskco.liberobc.client.business.services.InvoiceServiceMocked;
import nl.riskco.liberobc.web.pages.BasePage;

//@AuthorizeInstantiation("VIEWER")
public class InvoicesPage extends BasePage {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private InvoiceModalAgile modal2;

   public InvoicesPage(PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);

    IInvoiceService service = new InvoiceServiceMocked();
    List<InvoiceDomain> invoicesToTest2;
    invoicesToTest2 =service.getInvoices(1, 30);

    modal2 = new InvoiceModalAgile("modal", Model.of(new InvoiceDomain()));
    modal2.addCloseButton();
    modal2.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(modal2);

    DataView<InvoiceDomain> dataview = new DataView<InvoiceDomain>("rows",
            new ListDataProvider<InvoiceDomain>(invoicesToTest2)) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item<InvoiceDomain> item) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InvoiceDomain invoice = item.getModelObject();

            item.add(new Label("status", invoice.getStatus()));
            item.add(new Label("invoiceN", String.valueOf(invoice.getInvoiceGUID())));
            item.add(new Label("supplier", invoice.getSupplier()));
            item.add(new Label("customer", invoice.getCustomer()));
            item.add(new Label("amount", String.valueOf(invoice.getAmount())));

            item.add(new AjaxLink("showModal") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    modal2.setInvoiceModel(Model.of(invoice), target);
                    modal2.show(target);
                }
            }); 
        }
    };

    dataview.setItemsPerPage(10L);
    add(dataview);
    add(new PagingNavigator("navigator", dataview));
}

@Override
protected void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDetach();
}

}
```

**Markup of the modal**

```
<wicket:extend>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Invoice details</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th><wicket:message key="invoice-id">[invoice-id]</wicket:message></th>
                <td><div wicket:id="invoiceN"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><wicket:message key="invoice-status">[invoice-status]</wicket:message></th>
                <td><div wicket:id="status"></div></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <th><wicket:message key="invoice-customer">[invoice-customer]</wicket:message></th>
                <td><div wicket:id="customer"></div></td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><wicket:message key="invoice-supplier">[invoice-supplier]</wicket:message></th>
                <td><div wicket:id="supplier"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><wicket:message key="invoice-ibanSupplier">[invoice-ibanSupplier]</wicket:message></th>
                <td><div wicket:id="iban"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><wicket:message key="invoice-amount">[invoice-amount]</wicket:message></th>
                <td><div wicket:id="amount"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Approved</th>
                <td><form wicket:id="form"><input type="checkbox"  wicket:id="checkbox1"></form></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Early payment</th>
                <td><form wicket:id="form2"><input type="checkbox"  wicket:id="checkbox2"></form></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Paid (by customer)</th>
                <td><form wicket:id="form3"><input type="checkbox"  wicket:id="checkbox3"></form></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
 </div>
</wicket:extend>
```

**Java code of the modal**

```
package nl.riskco.liberobc.web.pages.invoices;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.CheckBox;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel;

import de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.behavior.BootstrapResourcesBehavior;
import de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.dialog.Modal;
import nl.riskco.liberobc.client.business.model.InvoiceDomain;


public class InvoiceModalAgile extends Modal<InvoiceDomain>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Label labelGuid;
private Label status;
private Label customer;
private Label iban;
private Label amountLabel;
private Label supplierLabel;
private CheckBox approved;
private CheckBox earlyPayment;
private CheckBox customerPaid;
private Form form;
private Form form2;
private Form form3;
private WebMarkupContainer header;
private WebMarkupContainer footer;

public InvoiceModalAgile(String id , IModel<InvoiceDomain> model) {
    super(id, model);

    add(form = new Form<>("form"));
    add(form2 = new Form<>("form2"));
    add(form3 = new Form<>("form3"));

    status = (new Label("status",model.getObject().getStatus()));
    status.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(status);

    supplierLabel = (new Label("supplier",model.getObject().getSupplier()));
    supplierLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(supplierLabel);


    labelGuid = new Label("invoiceN",model.getObject().getInvoiceGUID());
    labelGuid.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(labelGuid);

    customer = (new Label("customer",model.getObject().getCustomer()));
    customer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(customer);

    iban = new Label("iban",model.getObject().getIBANsupplier());
    iban.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(iban);

    amountLabel = new Label("amount",model.getObject().getAmount());
    amountLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(amountLabel);

    approved = new CheckBox("checkbox1");
    approved.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    approved.setEnabled(false);
    add(approved);
    form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(form);
    form.add(approved);

    earlyPayment = new CheckBox("checkbox2");
    earlyPayment.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    earlyPayment.setEnabled(false);
    add(earlyPayment);
    form2.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(form2);
    form2.add(earlyPayment);

    customerPaid = new CheckBox("checkbox3");
    customerPaid.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    customerPaid.setEnabled(false);
    add(customerPaid);
    form3.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(form3);
    form3.add(customerPaid);

    BootstrapResourcesBehavior.addTo(this);
}


public void setInvoiceModel(IModel<InvoiceDomain> invoice, AjaxRequestTarget target){


this.labelGuid.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getInvoiceGUID()));
target.add(labelGuid);

this.amountLabel.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getAmount()));
target.add(amountLabel);

this.status.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getStatus()));
target.add(status);

this.customer.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getCustomer()));
target.add(customer);

this.supplierLabel.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getSupplier()));
target.add(supplierLabel);

this.iban.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getIBANsupplier()));
target.add(iban);

this.approved.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getApprovedFlag()));
target.add(approved);
this.earlyPayment.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getOptForEarlyPaymentFlag()));
target.add(earlyPayment);
this.customerPaid.setDefaultModel(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getHasCustomerPaidFlag()));
target.add(customerPaid);

this.header(Model.of(String.valueOf(invoice.getObject().getInvoiceGUID())));
}

@Override
protected void onDetach() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onDetach();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the model object of the empty model that you pass at Modal construction. You need to use *dynamic* models for the properties.

Static/simple model:

```
label = new Label("staticValue", personModel.getObject().getName());
```

Here the label will use the name of the current person for each rendering.

Dynamic model:

```
label = new Label("staticValue", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {

   @Override public String getObject() { 
      return personModel.getObject().getName());
   }
}
```

You see that the dynamic version reads personModel's name lazily and it is called at each rendering of the Label. This way it will read the name of the person even if you put a new Person into the Label's Model.

In your case you need something like:

```
status = new Label("status", new PropertyModel(this, "model.object.status"));
```

For more information read: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models

Comment: Thank you for your help.
what you said is true, they are static, but I was not able to put it working for the modal header (most probably my fault).

Are you sure that this also works for the header of the modal.
Do you know if it is possible to do an ajax update of the header of the modal?
the other parameters worked because, for example, I can do target.add(customer);
but when I tried this for the header of the modal, which is on the parent, I got an internal error.

Comment: I guess the error is that the header doesn't have `setOutputMarkupId(true)` ?! If this is the case then just override `createHeader(String)` and call it on the result of `super.createHeader(id)`. Later use `#header(IModel<String> label)` to set a new model object for the header.